# Webpack duplication

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

I'm working on a `webpack` configuration file and I feel like I'm either missing something basic or totally misunderstanding what I thought was the main feature of `webpack`.  I've got a very basic `webpack.config.js` file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "app": [
            "./bundle.js"
        ]
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "bundle-[name].bundle.js",
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
}
```

If I use this file, I get a bundle that is 18.8Mb.  If I use `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, I see huge amounts of duplication everywhere.  In an effort to get it to combine all the common stuff together into a single additional bundle, I tried using the `CommonsChunkPlugin` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "app": [
            "./bundle.js"
        ]
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "bundle-[name].bundle.js",
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            minChunks: 2,
        })
    ]
}
```

With this, the bundle is still 18.8Mb, and a 5.79kb common bundle gets generated.  No luck.  Then I tried explicitly naming the bits I wanted to put in the common bundle with:

```
module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "common": ["react", "react-dom", "mobx", "mobx-react", "three", "three-trackballcontrols"],
        "app": [
            "./bundle.js"
        ]
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "bundle-[name].bundle.js",
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            minChunks: 2,
        })
    ]
}
```

Now I get two bundles, one that is 18Mb and another that is 2.95Mb (20.95Mb in total).  So still not moving in the right direction.  However, if I go through and try and spot the modules I think are being duplicated the most and define a resolution alias for them, *e.g.*,

```
module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "app": [
            "./bundle.js"
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "react": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "react"),
            "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "react-dom"),
            "mobx": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "mobx"),
            "mobx-react": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "mobx-react"),
            "rxjs": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "rxjs"),
            "three": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "three"),
            ...
        }
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "bundle-[name].bundle.js",
        "path": path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
}
```

Now, I get a single bundle that is only 6.1Mb.  Now I realize 6.1Mb is still pretty large (I'm not running the production optimizations with `webpack` at this point), but it is 1/3 the size of the original bundle, so that is a huge win.  But my disappointment is that I had to manually go through and figure out what the duplicated modules were.  I thought part of the whole point of `webpack` was that it would do this for me?

In general, things like `react` are marked as peer dependencies in the various packages.  But I know of at least one where `three` is listed as a dependency (not a peer dependency).  Could that be influencing all of this?  If so, then the problem is that for that particular module I'm not sure it makes sense to mark `three` as a peer dependency because one could not really predict whether it would make sense to add it as a dependency at the application level.

The bottom line is that I suspect I'm doing something wrong.  I'd like to fix this "the right way" so that `webpack` can do this automatically.  But I'm not sure why it is insisting on duplicating these packages.  I'm working with `webpack` 3.6.0, BTW.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is in your entry file of `bundle.js` ?
Are you using import or require?

Which output bundle is the largest one? I am guessing `bundle-app.bundle.js`